# Counting vectors with each entry appearing at least twice (in the context of tail bounds for limited independence)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

***Context:***
Consider the set $[n]^k$ and let $S \subset [n]^k$ be the subset of vectors $(v_1, \dots, v_k) \in [n]^k$ for which it holds that for all $i \in [k]$, there exists a $j \in [k]$ with $i \neq j$ such that $v_i = v_j$.
That is, $S$ contains all the vectors where each entry in the vector appears at least two times.

***Question:*** What is a reasonably tight upper bound for the size of $S$?

***More Context:***
This quantity needs to be upper bounded somewhat carefully in order to prove a tail bound for $k$-wise independent random variables.
I found two short proofs ([first proof (first answer)](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17466/chernoff-bounds-for-settings-with-limited-dependence) and [second proof (Lemma 2)](https://courses.cs.cornell.edu/cs6815/2019fa/lec3.pdf)) for such tail bounds of slightly differing qualities.
The two proofs provide different upper bounds on the size of $S$ and neither of them is clear to me. In particular, it seems to me that both proofs are undercounting the size of $S$.

The first link claims
$$ \vert S \vert \leq \binom{n}{k/2}\cdot (k/2)^k $$
And the second claims
$$ \vert S \vert \leq \binom{n}{k/2}\cdot k^{k/2}. $$

To be concrete, the proof in [second proof (Lemma 2)](https://courses.cs.cornell.edu/cs6815/2019fa/lec3.pdf) argues that there are at most $k/2$ distinct values in any vector $\vec{v}$, since every entry appears at least twice. Then they argue that there are $\binom{n}{k/2}$ distinct sets of $k/2$ vectors and then consider each entry appearing from $1$ to $k$ times (thus also counting illegal vectors here that would contain more than $k$ entries).
However, the proof seems to not account for the fact that if $\vec{v} \in S$,then so is every permutation of the entries of $\vec{v}$.
Is this indeed a mistake in the proof?

Comment: You are asking about two inequalities from some other links. For clarity, you should edit your question to include those inequalities, so people do not need to click a link and dig around to understand your question.

Comment: Thanks. Added both upper bounds to the question.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I am getting $\vert S \vert \leq (6e^2 k n)^{k/2}$, but not entirely sure whether that’s correct or tight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim that
$
|S|\le \binom{n}{k/2}(k/2)^k
$
from the first source is correct. We can generate all vectors in $S$ at least once, plus some extras, using the following procedure.

- Choose a subset $M\subseteq [n]$ such that $|M|=k/2$, in $\binom{n}{k/2}$ ways.
- Choose a vector $(v_1,\dots,v_k)$, where $v_i\in M$ for each $i\in \{1,\dots,k\}$, in $(k/2)^k$ ways.

The proof given for the claim
$$
|S|\stackrel?{\le }\binom{n}{k/2}k^{k/2}
$$
from the second source is invalid, for the exact reason you said; specifying the number of times each number appears does not determine the order they appear in. However, it may be true that the displayed inequality is true for a different reason.

Comment: Oh I see. Even thought $M$ has $k/2$ distinct indices, the vectors I generate also include those that contain less distinct indices, since I can keep picking the same elements from M. Got it, thanks!